# Bogus URL access causing server to hang

Tags: asp.net, iis, firewall

When a unavailable url is accessed, we internally raise an exception and email to support team. We do this to identify is there is hidden error in our web application. Couple of days back, suddenly there was a huge number of access to unavailable url which added load to server and casued SMTP to queue large exception emails. This attempt has brought IIS completely down and none of the applications are accessible.

How to prevent this? Is there any other option like firewall etc to disallow continues request from same ip. I have seen this behavior in google. How can we achieve that?

Comment: try this.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750213.aspx

Comment: or you can try another approach. that is instead of sending mail on every 404, collect them all in the database and run a job that sends a mail with all the 404s once a day. you could limit the size of your mail and chunk to say to 1000 404s a mail or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest caching already sent notifications. Before your application sends email, it can check if this error is already reported.

And you can set the cache validity to, say 1 minute, so you get maximum 1 same email/minute.
It is quite easy to implement in ASP.NET.

Comment: but still continues bogus url access will add load to server. how can we prevent that?